# How to write INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE,SELECT,Nested SELECT command using a prepared statement in SQLite for Android Application?

Tags: android, sqlite, select, prepared-statement, subquery

Recently I got to know that raw query in android can not prevent SQL injection and thus I decided to convert all queries in Prepared statement which is SQL injection prevention. But I don't know how to convert complex queries in Prepared Statement.

I want to convert below queries:

1.

```
select
    *
FROM
    TableName
where
    (tab1col1 in(SELECT tab2Col2 FROM MasterTable where tab2col1='Y')
    or  tab1col2 = CV.TRUE)
order by
    tab1col3, tab1col4, tab1col5,tab1col6
```

2.

```
Select
    * ,count(*) as TOTAL_COUNT ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tabCol1 LIKE '%todayDate%' THEN 1 ELSE  0 END) as  TOTAL_COL1_COUNT
from
    TableName
group by tabCol2;
```

Comment: It would be really great if you provide solution rather than suggestion in question @Kling Klang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rawQuery` to prevent injection by passing any arguments via the selectionargs (2nd parameter).

SQL injection, wouldn't apply to either of the queries, as they are hard coded and have no user generated/supplied inputs.

e.g. your first query could be (assuming that, 'Y' and CV.TRUE are passed as parameters (i.e. user generated/supplied) for the sake of demonstration) :-

```
public Cursor query1raw(String indicator1,String indicator2) {
    String sql = "SELECT * " +

            " FROM TableName " +
            " WHERE (tab1col1" +
            "     IN(" +
            "         SELECT tab2col2 " +
            "         FROM MasterTable " +
            "         WHERE tab2col1=?)" +
            "     OR  tab1col2=?)" +
            " ORDER BY tab1col3, tab1col4,tab1col5,tab1col6";
    String[] args = new String[]{indicator1,indicator2};
    return mDB.rawQuery(sql,args);
}
```

However, the convenience methods are generally recommended rather than `rawQuery` or `execSQL` when they can be used, again using bound strings via arguments, the above, using the `query` convenience method could be :-

```
public Cursor query1(String indicator1, String indicator2) {
    String whereclause = "(tab1col1 IN(SELECT tab2col2 FROM MasterTable WHERE tab2col1=?) OR tab1col2=?)";
    String[] whereargs = new String[] {indicator1,indicator2};
    String order_columns = "tab1col3,tab1col4,tab1col5,tab1col6";
    return mDB.query("TableName",null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,order_columns);
}
```

You wouldn't use prepared statements themselves as they are restricted to returning single values, not a row or rows with multiple columns.

---

#### Warning not advised

However, you could, if you really wanted, use :-

```
public Cursor query1ps(String indicator1,String indicator2) {
    String[] whereargs = new String[] {indicator1,indicator2};
    SQLiteStatement stmnt = mDB.compileStatement("SELECT * " +
            " FROM TableName " +
            " WHERE (tab1col1" +
            "     IN(" +
            "         SELECT tab2col2 " +
            "         FROM MasterTable " +
            "         WHERE tab2col1=?)" +
            "     OR  tab1col2=?)" +
            " ORDER BY tab1col3, tab1col4,tab1col5,tab1col6");
    stmnt.bindAllArgsAsStrings(whereargs);
    Log.d("PREPAREDSQL",stmnt.toString());
    String sql = stmnt.toString().replace("SQLiteProgram:","");
    return mDB.rawQuery(sql,null);
}
```

- As you can see all the prepared statement is doing as such, is substituting the arguments, so has little benefit over the other methods. This would also be dependant upon **SQLIteProgram:** remaining constant.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT for providing me solution

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent SQL injections is to use parameters. (In some PHP APIs, the only way to get parameters is to use prepared statements, but that is not one of the warts in the Android database API.)

Just write `?` for any string, and pass the values separately:

```java
String name = ...;
String password = ...;
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SomeCol FROM Users WHERE Name = ? AND Password = ?",
                     new String[]{ name, password });
```

Please not that SQL injection could happen only if you have string values that are controlled by the (potentially-hostile) user. Your queries above do not look as if this were the case.